# Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a navigation example using react router and stuck in an error. Please find the code

```
    app.js
    -------

    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Routes from './routes';

    ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('react-container'));

    routes.js
    ---------

    import { React,Component } from 'react';
    import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler,Router } from 'react-router';
    import Page1 from './page1';
    import Home from './home';

    export default class Routes extends Component {

        constructor() {
        super();
      } 

      render() {
        return (
                <Router >
                    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
                        <Route name="page1" path="/1" component={ Page1 }/>
                    </Route>
                </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    home.js
    -------

    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class Home extends Component {

        constructor() {
        super();
      } 

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Header />
              {this.props.children}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    page1.js
    --------

    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class Page1 extends Component {

        constructor() {
        super();
      } 

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1> Page 1 </h1>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I have babel transformer to convert from es6 to es5 and I get the following error on loading the app,

```
    Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a component class, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.
```

Can anyone help me in troubleshooting this issue ?

Comment: Not totally sure, but you aren't importing `Header` from anywhere.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for the pointer. Thats was not the root cause though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your routes.js. You are wrapping your routes inside of a component, then passing that to `ReactDOM.render`. You should be passing the jsx directly. My suggestions would be to unwrap routes from your class, and just export the jsx.

```
routes.js
---------

import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import Page1 from './page1'
import Home from './home'

let routes = 
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route name="page1" path="/1" component={Page1}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>

export default routes
```

The error is complaining that you are passing a class, rather then calling `React.createElement`. Remember that this:

```
let someElement = <div>Hello</div>
```

Will turn into this:

```
var someElement = React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  "Hello"
)
```

Comment: Spot on ! Thanks ! But once I do the change , I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined" in route.js file

Comment: Make sure you have `import React from 'react'` at the top of that file.. you wrote that improperly in your example.

Comment: Thanks ! that addressed all compilation issues.